# Fetching DateTime from Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, datetime

I am creating project using nodejs and mysql. I have unique kind of problem. I am fetching the data from table.All the results coming from db is correct except datetime.In my db date is stored like: `2016-11-02 11:16:10` and the type of  table field is `timestamp`. When i query the data am getting date like this format

```
Tue Nov 01 2016 10:19:17 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) } ]
```

I want to get the data which is stored in db like `2016-11-02 11:16:10`.

Here is the Query am using:

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM PEN_WFM_TXN_Details Where customerID = ?";
        req.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
            var query = connection.query(sql, [data[0].customer_uuid], function(err, rows) {
                console.log("klkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk")
                console.log(rows)
                for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                    for(j=0; j<rows.length; j++){
                        if(data[i].uuid == rows[j].topology_tag_uuid){
                            transactions.push({
                                topology_uuid:rows[j].topology_tag_uuid,
                                status:exports.getTransactionStatusByCode(rows[j].status),
                                creationTime:rows[j].modifiedTime,
                                name:data[i].name,
                                txnId:rows[j].txnID
                            })

                        }

                    }
                }
                res.send(transactions)  
            })

        })
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a JavaScript date time object. You can get the day/mongh/year/minuts .... and format it manually here is a link the [Date Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Simple Solution is set the dateStrings settings in mysql connection like:

```
app.use(connection(mysql,{  
    dateStrings         :'date',
    database            : "PEN_GUI",
    multipleStatements  : true
},'request
```

'));